# Infinite loop because of misusing ReactJS Router, useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

In the child component, I'm calling an API then pushing to a different route, this causes App component to re-render because its location prop key (location.key) keeps changing causing the child to keep re-mounting ( I know re-rendering the parent should only re-render the child not re-mount it, but this is what's happening when I tried passing empty array to the second arg in `useEffect`, `useEffect(() => {}, []);`

I can stop App from re-rendering through shouldComponenUpdate, and update it only when location.pathname changes not when the key changes, but is there a better way?

**Parent.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {
           ....,
           ....,
           location,
          }= props;
    if (props.location.pathname.includes('/x');
    push('/x');
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (
      this.props.location.pathname !== nextProps.location.pathname ||
      this.state.match.path !== nextState.match.path
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

render() {
    <Child/>
}
```

**Child.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Y.ID) {
      fetchYDetails();
    }
}, [fetchYDetails, Y.ID]);
```

**Model.js**

```
effects: dispatch => ({
    fetchYDetails() {
        const response = await request({ ...});
        if (!response.error) {
            dispatch(push('/z'));
        };
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since you are using useEffect you should also switch from class based components to function based components with `useState`.

Comment: can you add full code of child.js? i want to see what is Y.ID and fetchYDetails

Comment: Your `if` condition in `constructor` is invalid. Please check and edit before we can answer your question

Comment: Ignore it, i just added it to show that i need a location prop for the Parent component, but why do you think its invalid?@MohammadRezaKhedri